# define Namespace with prefix in child nodes in xslt

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

Is there any way to define (namespace with prefix) in child node of xml using xslt. so that my namespace apply to its decendents also, i have use

```
<xsl:element name="abc" namespace="{$prmPafNamespace}">
```

but it create default namespace.

when i use it like below

```
<xsl:element name="paf:abc" namespace="{$prmPafNamespace}">
    <xsl:element name="paf:child_abc"/>
</xsl:element>
```

then it gives error that 'paf' is not defined, how to solve this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the namespace on each element e.g.

```
<xsl:element name="paf:abc" namespace="{$prmPafNamespace}">
    <xsl:element name="paf:child_abc" namespace="{$prmPafNamespace}"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: thanks Martin it works but is there any alternative because i have a very long xml and use the same namespace for every child node looks odd ...

Comment: I am not aware of any shorter alternative, if you want the namespace to be dynamic then you have to specify it on each element you create dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an `xmlns:paf="{$prmPafNamespace}"` attribute to your document/element, but I'm not sure whether it will work with a dynamic namespace URI.