# XSLT Dynamic namespace with tags accessing the prefix

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

Below `xslt` composing a soap message with dynamic namespace, but the children are fixed and using the prefix at the design time itself.

While initial parse, ptr at the root level said to be undeclared namespace.
I can't create the root and child elements dynamically since the hierarchy is
huge.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ptr="{$nameSpace}">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <ptr:root>
        <ptr:child_1>
        <ptr:child_2>

.
.
.
.
.
```

Note:
This may looks like similar question to ..
[define Namespace with prefix in child nodes in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978583/define-namespace-with-prefix-in-child-nodes-in-xslt)
, but the difference is that my root/child are fixed hierarchy, can't be dynamic element.

Engine used is datapower.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, or how you are trying to achieve it, or how it is failing. However, use of attribute value templates in a namespace declaration ( `xmlns:ptr="{...}"` ) isn't going to work.

Comment: ( xmlns:ptr="{...}" ) isn't working. while initial parsing, for the below root and child which is using ptr prefix. trying to check the ptr declaration at the head since its initial parsing, its not evaluating the value of the variable  mentioned for ptr. and uses directly the variable name with {$xx} as namespace which is wrong. All I need is... namespace alone need to be set dynamically.

Comment: You're going to have to explain more carefully. What is the input, what is the required output, and how do they relate to each other?